# How to make dropdown selection dynamic asp2.0

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I am learning jquery, and I have a dropdownlist as such:

```
Option 1 
Option 2
Option 3
```

On select option 1- show textboxOption1 and button

On select option 2- show textboxOption2 and button

On Select option 3- show textboxOption3 and button and so on...

I would like to know how to make this select dynamic and display text box and buttons associated with the options. Because if I have eg. 10 options the current code will be too long and become messy and not maintainable.

I am using textbox controls.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    hide();
    $("select[id$='DropDownListFilter']").change(function () {
        var optionValue = $("select[id$='DropDownListFilter'] option:selected").val();
        if (optionValue == 'Option1') {
            $('#Option1').hide(0).delay().fadeIn(1000);
            $("#Option2").hide('slow');
            $('#Option3').hide();
        } else if (optionValue == 'Option2') {
            $("#Option2").hide(0).delay().fadeIn(1000);
            $('#Option1').hide('slow');
            $('#Option3').hide();
        } else if (optionValue == 'Option3') {
            $('#Option3').hide().delay().fadeIn(1000);
            $("#Option1").hide();
            $('#Option2').hide('slow');
        }
        else {
            $("#Option1").hide('slow');
            $('#Option2').hide('slow');
            $('#Option3').hide('slow');
        }
    });
});

    function hide() {
        $('#Option1').hide();
        $("#Option2").hide();
        $('#Option3').hide();
    }
```

HTML: Update - id=option added to each div on Patel suggestion.

```
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-bg">
                    <div id="filterbystatus" class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="FilterStatus" CssClass="label label-default" runat="server">Filter By</asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListFilter" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                            <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Tag</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Description</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Status</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                <div id="option1" class="form-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilterByTag" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Tag..." />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnTagFitler" CssClass="btn btn-primary col-md-6" runat="server" Text="Search"/>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="option2" class="form-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilterByDescription" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Description..."></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDescFilter" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Is this the behavior you're expecting? -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk0orxyo/)

Comment: @Patel Yes this is, but I cannot select the divs?

Comment: What do you mean by select the divs? Explain, please.

Comment: $('div[id^="Option"]').hide(); //Hide all Div with Options << does not hide the divs. @Patel

Comment: It hides the div and another div comes up. Check the text in button changing (when you change select) as they're all different buttons in different divs!

Comment: Yeah you're correct. So now it hides all the divs on page load. But select an option does not show the other div? @Patel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83312/discussion-between-patel-and-harry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you this:

```
$("select[id$='DropDownListFilter']").change(function () { // bind the change event
    var optionValue = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); // get the value of selected option
    $('div[id^="option"]').hide(); // initially hide all the text box's parent div
    $('input[type="text"][id*="'+optionValue+'"]').closest('div').show(); // finally show the respective textbox div
});
```

```js
    $("select[id$='DropDownListFilter']").change(function() { // bind the change event
      var optionValue = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); // get the value of selected option
      $('input[type="text"][id^="txt"]').hide(); // initially hide all the text boxes
      $('#' + optionValue).show(); // finally show the respective textbox
    });
```

```css
input[type="text"][id^="txt"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dd-DropDownListFilter'>
  <option value=''>select</option>
  <option value='txt1'>txt1</option>
  <option value='txt2'>txt2</option>
  <option value='txt3'>txt3</option>
</select>
<select id='dd-DropDownListFilter'>
  <option value=''>select</option>
  <option value='txt4'>txt4</option>
  <option value='txt5'>txt5</option>
  <option value='txt6'>txt6</option>
</select>
<select id='dd-DropDownListFilter'>
  <option value=''>select</option>
  <option value='txt7'>txt7</option>
  <option value='txt8'>txt8</option>
  <option value='txt9'>txt9</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='txt1' placeholder='txt1'>
<input type='text' id='txt2' placeholder='txt2'>
<input type='text' id='txt3' placeholder='txt3'>
<input type='text' id='txt4' placeholder='txt4'>
<input type='text' id='txt5' placeholder='txt5'>
<input type='text' id='txt6' placeholder='txt6'>
<input type='text' id='txt7' placeholder='txt7'>
<input type='text' id='txt8' placeholder='txt8'>
<input type='text' id='txt9' placeholder='txt9'>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using asp2.0, and textbox control, so each id is different for the textboxes, updated the question.

Comment: @Harry can you post your generated html from the page? Just want to know how does it look like? the ids of controls.

Comment: Could you explain what this line is doing?  $('input[type="text"][id*="'+optionValue+'"]').closest('div').show();

Comment: Reason I am asking is, what if the div does not have a textbox, what if it has different controls in it. Then it will not show up... with current code.

Comment: @Harry It is only applicable on those divs which has input type text. if they do then show/hide would work.

Comment: I think the original $('#' +option).show() option is what I am looking for. as I did not want it to be tied down to just textboxes. But does not work, although it selects in console log and shows it on page while discussing with @Patel